# How can I put two elements inside one without any overflow?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
    border:1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: inherit;
   width: inherit;
}

.child{
    border:1px solid red;
   margin-top: 1px;
 padding: 4px 8px 30px 7px;
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 100%;
}

span{
   color: #222;
 display: block;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

As you see, `div.child` element is out of view and the word of `six` isn't visible now. How can I fix it?

Actually that's because of the height of that `span`. The `height` of `div.child` is `100%`, so its `height` will be the same as `div.parent`. While there is a `span` in the top of `div.parent` and then undoubtedly the `height` of `div.child` should be less than `100%`.

---

**Note1:** I can fix the problem by using `box-sizing: border-box;` for `div.child`. But I don't want to use it. Because the most of my website's users use old browsers like IE7.

**Note2:** As I've commented in the snippet above, the height of `div.main` is based on `%`. So I cannot use `calc()` at all, because there isn't anything based on the pixel. Also `calc()` will not be supported on the old browsers.

**Note3:** The final `height` of `div.main` should be `100px`, not more.

Comment: Do you like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d7o23dv7/

Comment: @Mojtaba What did you do exactly? I cannot find what you've changed from my codes.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure if you like to have a full height scroll. That's why I didn't post it as an answer. I moved the scroll for overflow to the parent and changed the padding of the child. I think you are done the most parts. To see the differences: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=e039z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use "calc"

- The ***span*** view's height = **30px**
- The ***.child*** view's:

  - border = **1px * 2 = 2px** (top and bottom)
  - padding-bottom = **4px**
  - padding-top = **4px**
  - margin-top = **1px**
- The ***.parent*** view's border = **1px * 2 = 2px** (top and bottom)

### Replace:

**.child** view's height must be:

> Height = 100% - (30 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 2)

```
.child{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 7px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 43px);
}
```

### Result:

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 7px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

span{
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit 1:

Without using calc()

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 7px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:30px;
}

span{
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit 2:

**Highlight** changes.

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top: 1px;

  /* removed */  padding: 4px 8px 30px 7px;
  /*  added  */  padding: 4px 8px 4px 7px;

  overflow: scroll;

  /* removed */  height: 100%;
 
  /*  added  */  position:absolute;
  /*  added  */  top:0;
  /*  added  */  bottom: 0;
  /*  added  */  width:100%;
  /*  added  */  margin-top:30px;
}

span{
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## JUST REMOVE LINES WITH PREFIX /* removed */

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top: 1px;

  /* removed   padding: 4px 8px 30px 7px;*/
  /*  added  */  padding: 4px 8px 4px 7px;

  overflow: scroll;

  /* removed   height: 100%;*/
 
  /*  added  */  position:absolute;
  /*  added  */  top:0;
  /*  added  */  bottom: 0;
  /*  added  */  width:100%;
  /*  added  */  margin-top:30px;
}

span{
  color: #222;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use `calc()`

Comment: @stack see "edit 1" without using calc(), you have to set the top and bottom to 0, and set the position to absolute with the margin-top = title's height

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. Just can you please add a comment in the front of new lines you added ? I want to find them easily and use them into my real codes.

Comment: Just as a note, `width:100%;` is already there `;-)` but you commented it as `/* added */`

Comment: Just as a note, I don't see `width:100%` in your code.

Comment: Oh .. You are right .. I guess that line was in my mind *(forgot to write it)*

Comment: Oh wait .. still `six` is out of box .. `:-(`

Answer (score 1):

Make the child div smaller

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;   /* in reality this isn't based on the pixel, it is % */ 
}

.parent{
    border:1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: inherit;
   width: inherit;
}

.child{
    border:1px solid red;
   margin-top: 1px;
 padding: 4px 8px 30px 7px;
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 50%; /*make it smaller*/
}

span{
   color: #222;
 display: block;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: BYekan,'BYekan', Tahoma;
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span>title</span>
    <div class="child">
      one<br> two<br> three<br> four<br> five<br> six<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvtoe .. just can you please tell me why `height: 50%`? Where `50%` comes from?

Comment: height comes from parent div which is .parent... since no style is set it is by default taking .main's height value which is 100px...

Comment: Well this approach isn't standard at all .. As I've mentioned , the `height` of `div.main` is based on the `%` .. So it isn't constant. And `50%` isn't correct for all screens. I means sometimes `50%` is too much and sometimes else it is low.

Comment: set parent max-height to 100px...? as you said in Note3: The final height of div.main should be 100px, not more.

Comment: Look, `100px` is a test. In reality the that's like this: `div.main{ height: 54%; }`